# Django 1.5 class Meta has no attribute 'verbose_name_plural'

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-1.5

I have upgraded my project from Django1.3 to Django1.5
But am getting an error "AttributeError: class Meta has no attribute 'verbose_name_plural'"

### Base class

```
class PortalModelBase(models.base.ModelBase):
   def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attr_meta = attrs.pop('Meta', None)

        try:
           is_global = attr_meta.is_global
           del attr_meta.is_global
        except AttributeError:
           is_global = False

        attrs['Meta'] = attr_meta
        model = super(PortalModelBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        model._meta.is_global = is_global
        return model

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

### Model class

Having meta class as PortalModelBase

```
class PortalModel(models.Model):  
   __metaclass__ = PortalModelBase

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='name*', help_text='Enter Name', blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024, verbose_name='Description', help_text="Enter a description", blank=True,null=True, default='')
   createdby = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   createdon = models.DateTimeField()
   modifiedby = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   modifiedon = models.DateTimeField()


  def __init__(self_, *args, **kwargs):
    log.info("Portal model initializing")
    if kwargs:
        d = copy.copy(kwargs)
        for key in d:

            if key not in self_._meta.get_all_field_names():
                #The key given by the dictionary is not in the model.
                #Django, by design, will throw an exception
                #this prevents that
                kwargs.pop(key)

    return super(PortalModel, self_).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

## Inherited class

```
class TestIP(PortalModel):

     address = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='VIP')

   class Meta:
       abstract = False
       verbose_name = 'testIP'
      verbose_name_plural = "testips"
```

Tried to call verbose_name_plural in views.py getting error
"AttributeError: class Meta has no attribute 'verbose_name_plural'"

### Views.py

```
kwargs[TestIP.Meta.verbose_name_plural.lower().replace(' ', '')] = table
```

It works fine in Django1.3, Please help to figure out this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer

In Django1.5 we should access meta class like 'TestIP._meta.verbose_name_plural'

I have changed

```
kwargs[TestIP.Meta.verbose_name_plural.lower().replace(' ', '')] = table
```

to

```
kwargs[TestIP._meta.verbose_name_plural.lower().replace(' ', '')] = table
```

It works fine in django1.5